# Translate cURL command into PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

I have a cURL command I want to translate into PHP.

```
curl -XPOST -H"X-Ovh-Application: 7kbG7Bk7S9Nt7ZSV" -H "Content-type: application/json" \
https://ca.api.ovh.com/1.0/auth/credential  -d '{
    "accessRules": [
        {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ],
    "redirection":"https://www.mywebsite.com/"
}'
```

The cURL command is returning the right values:

```
{"consumerKey":"6br3ends9irOEWuBDoKHVOjNk54LEQlxya","state":"pendingValidation","validationUrl":"https://eu.api.ovh.com/auth/?credentialToken=W6lERcYmhvrSewowZglIP2ZJYJ8DsiUlFpWaVGO5UtebHjO431nOcS7UMddOgebk"}
```

What I tried in PHP :

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ca.api.ovh.com/1.0/auth/credential");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n    \"accessRules\": [\n        {\n            \"method\": \"GET\",\n            \"path\": \"/*\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"redirection\":\"https://www.mywebsite.com/\"\n}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Ovh-Application: 7kbG7Bk7S9Nt7ZSV";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($result);
```

The script doesn't return the expected value :

```
{"message":"Received not described parameters: ({\"accessRules\":{\"method\":\"GET\",\"path\":\"/*\"}}) while calling credential"}
```

Maybe because the post data isn't well formated ?

Comment: You should not build json like that. Instead, build the array structure you need and use `json_encode()` to get the required string.

Comment: Can you use guzzle ? If you have composer/a framework in your project ? It's easier and better.

Comment: Yes I have guzzle in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to real json object for data posting. You can that with json_encode() function that converting array object of php to json data.

**Can you try following code:**

```
$data = ['accessRules' => ['method' => 'GET', 'path' => '/*'], 'redirection' => 'https://www.mywebsite.com/'];    
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ca.api.ovh.com/1.0/auth/credential");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Ovh-Application: 7kbG7Bk7S9Nt7ZSV";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: It's valid but I have : `{"message":"Invalid application key"}`

Comment: I changed my answer for this line: $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; line.

Comment: In my opinion, the error returns for this key: 7kbG7Bk7S9Nt7ZSV.
I tried curl request without php on the terminal, it returns to me {"message":"Invalid application key"}

Answer (score 0):

You could use this site also, https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ it translates from raw curl command to PHP.

Updated:

From the ovh doc you could use an OVH api client for PHP, this is the example that they have in their [doc site](https://ca.api.ovh.com/console/#/auth/credential#POST):

```
<?php
/**
 * First, download the latest release of PHP wrapper on github
 * And include this script into the folder with extracted files
 */
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use \Ovh\Api;

/**
 * Instanciate an OVH Client.
 * You can generate new credentials with full access to your account on
 * the token creation page
 */
$ovh = new Api( 'xxxxxxxxxx',  // Application Key
                'xxxxxxxxxx',  // Application Secret
                'ovh-eu',      // Endpoint of API OVH Europe (List of available endpoints)
                'xxxxxxxxxx'); // Consumer Key

$result = $ovh->post('/auth/credential', array(
    'accessRules' => 'xxxx', // Required: Access required for your application (type: auth.AccessRule[])
));

print_r( $result );
```

Comment: This is what I did

Comment: Updated the post, using the OVH api client from they side.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I need to retrieve the consumerKey

Answer (score 0):

first off, this is a terrible way to set a json with php:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n    \"accessRules\": [\n        {\n            \"method\": \"GET\",\n            \"path\": \"/*\"\n        }\n    ],\n    \"redirection\":\"https://www.mywebsite.com/\"\n}");
```

try instead:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
    'accessRules' => array(
        0 => array(
            'method' => 'GET',
            'path' => '/*'
        )
    ),
    'redirection' => 'https://www.mywebsite.com/'
)));
```

but in your curl cli invocation you send the header `Content-type: application/json`

so why does your php code send the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  ? try to fix that,

```
$headers[] = "Content-type: application/json";
```

does your code work then?